# Save JSON reponse in raw format in a json file

Tags: java, android, json, file, gson

I am trying to save JSON Response that i get from this URL in a JSON file in android.

[Json Response](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22)

I am able to save the Data into JSON format, but its not quite the same though.The Data saved in JSON file is Something like this :

```
ForecastResponse{city = 'City{country = 'IN',coord = 'Coord{lon = '72.0',lat = '23.0'}',name = 'State of Gujarāt',id = '1270770.0'}',cnt = '37.0',cod = '200',message = '0.0046',list = '[ListItem{dt = '1.5375204E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '01d',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '41.53',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '38.0',pressure = '1012.98',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '0.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '353.002',speed = '6.22'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5375312E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02d',description = 'few clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '801.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '39.97',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '32.0',pressure = '1011.35',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '12.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '359.002',speed = '4.92'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.537542E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '04n',description = 'overcast clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '804.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '35.82',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '33.0',pressure = '1012.65',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '92.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '353.5',speed = '4.75'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5375528E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '04n',description = 'overcast clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '804.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '33.51',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '34.0',pressure = '1012.86',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '88.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '341.5',speed = '4.81'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5375636E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '04n',description = 'overcast clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '804.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '31.51',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '46.0',pressure = '1012.12',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '92.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '32.0',speed = '2.8'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5375744E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02n',description = 'few clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '801.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '28.74',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '62.0',pressure = '1012.51',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '20.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '101.0',speed = '1.42'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5375852E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '04d',description = 'broken clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '803.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '28.89',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '62.0',pressure = '1015.08',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '64.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '66.0012',speed = '1.36'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.537596E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '04d',description = 'overcast clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '804.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '31.99',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '55.0',pressure = '1015.56',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '100.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '24.001',speed = '3.42'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5376068E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '04d',description = 'broken clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '803.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '32.91',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '49.0',pressure = '1013.1',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '76.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '330.002',speed = '3.92'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5376176E9',rain = 'null',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '03d',description = 'scattered clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '802.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '35.15',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '44.0',pressure = '1011.77',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '36.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '333.501',speed = '3.56'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5376284E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '10n',description = 'light rain',main = 'Rain',id = '500.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '29.36',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '71.0',pressure = '1014.41',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '76.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '47.5027',speed = '2.62'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5376392E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '03n',description = 'scattered clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '802.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '27.0',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '82.0',pressure = '1015.89',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '48.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '55.0006',speed = '2.67'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.53765E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '03n',description = 'scattered clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '802.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '25.87',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '87.0',pressure = '1015.38',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '32.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '35.0044',speed = '1.42'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5376608E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02n',description = 'few clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '801.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '25.01',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '91.0',pressure = '1015.74',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '12.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '357.505',speed = '1.56'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5376716E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02d',description = 'few clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '801.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '27.67',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '80.0',pressure = '1017.56',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '24.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '289.501',speed = '1.28'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5376824E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02d',description = 'few clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '801.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '32.82',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '62.0',pressure = '1017.55',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '20.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '290.501',speed = '2.47'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5376932E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '10d',description = 'light rain',main = 'Rain',id = '500.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '34.52',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '53.0',pressure = '1015.2',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '56.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '340.0',speed = '3.02'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.537704E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '10d',description = 'light rain',main = 'Rain',id = '500.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '33.81',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '53.0',pressure = '1014.61',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '56.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '7.00308',speed = '1.91'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5377148E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '10n',description = 'moderate rain',main = 'Rain',id = '501.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '26.56',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '87.0',pressure = '1017.28',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '68.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '17.0002',speed = '1.86'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5377256E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '10n',description = 'moderate rain',main = 'Rain',id = '501.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '24.22',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '94.0',pressure = '1018.2',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '56.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '68.5074',speed = '1.76'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5377364E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '10n',description = 'light rain',main = 'Rain',id = '500.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '24.05',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '94.0',pressure = '1016.88',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '32.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '133.004',speed = '1.23'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5377472E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02n',description = 'few clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '801.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '23.2',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '95.0',pressure = '1017.28',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '12.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '269.003',speed = '1.31'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.537758E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02d',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '26.75',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '88.0',pressure = '1019.33',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '8.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '285.0',speed = '2.17'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5377688E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02d',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '32.59',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '76.0',pressure = '1019.72',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '8.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '304.504',speed = '2.56'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5377796E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02d',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '34.53',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '62.0',pressure = '1017.56',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '8.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '346.001',speed = '2.16'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5377904E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02d',description = 'few clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '801.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '33.57',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '55.0',pressure = '1016.6',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '12.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '30.5009',speed = '1.68'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5378012E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '03n',description = 'scattered clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '802.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '28.55',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '74.0',pressure = '1018.24',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '48.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '153.0',speed = '1.61'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.537812E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '03n',description = 'scattered clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '802.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '27.65',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '73.0',pressure = '1018.81',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '36.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '194.503',speed = '3.26'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5378228E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '04n',description = 'broken clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '803.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '26.89',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '75.0',pressure = '1018.35',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '56.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '252.001',speed = '3.31'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5378336E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02n',description = 'few clouds',main = 'Clouds',id = '801.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '25.53',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '78.0',pressure = '1018.48',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '12.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '280.015',speed = '4.67'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5378444E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '01d',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '26.99',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '81.0',pressure = '1020.49',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '0.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '289.001',speed = '4.32'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5378552E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '01d',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '31.94',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '63.0',pressure = '1020.85',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '0.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '298.003',speed = '3.56'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.537866E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '01d',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '35.24',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '50.0',pressure = '1018.07',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '0.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '303.001',speed = '2.66'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5378768E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '02d',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '35.23',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '39.0',pressure = '1016.19',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '8.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'd'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '289.501',speed = '2.35'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5378876E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '01n',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '29.37',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '46.0',pressure = '1017.9',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '0.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '268.516',speed = '4.26'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5378984E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '01n',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '26.89',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '49.0',pressure = '1019.04',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '0.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '269.502',speed = '5.31'}'}, ListItem{dt = '1.5379092E9',rain = 'Rain{}',dt_txt = 'null',weather = '[WeatherItem{icon = '01n',description = 'clear sky',main = 'Clear',id = '800.0'}]',main = 'Main{temp = '24.88',temp_min = '0.0',grnd_level = '0.0',temp_kf = '0.0',humidity = '70.0',pressure = '1018.34',sea_level = '0.0',temp_max = '0.0'}',clouds = 'Clouds{all = '0.0'}',sys = 'Sys{pod = 'n'}',wind = 'Wind{deg = '274.0',speed = '5.03'}'}]'}
```

which is not relevant when i want to get it back and pass it using Gson Library. I want to save JSON Response as it was got from JSONResponse.

My Code for Saving and reading from JSON file is following :

```
package android.example.com.weatheralertpractice;

import android.content.Context;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

//  This will Handle the File Reading/Writing on to the Internal Storage...
public class FileHandling {

    private String FileName;
    private Context context;
    private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    private FileInputStream fileInputStream;

    private File file;

    public FileHandling(Context context, String FileName) {
        this.context = context;
        this.FileName = FileName;
        file = new File(this.context.getFilesDir(), this.FileName);
    }

    public void WriteJsonResponseOntoTheFile(String FileContent) {
        try {
            fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(FileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream.write(FileContent.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String ReadJsonResponsefromTheFile() {
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            int size = fileInputStream.available();
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[size];
            fileInputStream.read(byteArray);
            fileInputStream.close();
            String GetResponse = new String(byteArray);
            return GetResponse;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u able to save data in file?

Comment: Yes, I have posted the data in a file as well. @RavindraKushwaha it's not the same because it uses single quote. So, i need help regarding that. I want to save data as raw format without any changes.

Comment: Than whats the probelm now @Avi , You just read the data from th file and parse it in int `GSON` parser

Comment: Yes the data saved in file is not valid json.

Comment: Means, you are not able to save whole `JSON` response into your file?

Comment: no i am able to save whole response but not in valid format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have solved my own problem by using GSON library's own .toJSON methos which will convert the response got from retrofit into appropriate JSON format, it was a silly mistake from calling side.

i have changed my code from ->

```
fileHandling.WriteJsonResponseOntoTheFile(response.body().toString());
```

to this ->

```
 fileHandling.WriteJsonResponseOntoTheFile(gson.toJson(response));
```

output ->

```
{"city":{"coord":{"lat":23.0,"lon":72.0},"country":"IN","id":1270770.0,"name":"State of Gujarāt"},"cnt":37.0,"cod":"200","list":[{"clouds":{"all":0.0},"dt":1.5375204E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":38.0,"pressure":1012.98,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":41.53,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"01d","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":353.002,"speed":6.22}},{"clouds":{"all":12.0},"dt":1.5375312E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":32.0,"pressure":1011.35,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":39.97,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"few clouds","icon":"02d","id":801.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":359.002,"speed":4.92}},{"clouds":{"all":92.0},"dt":1.537542E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":33.0,"pressure":1012.65,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":35.82,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n","id":804.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":353.5,"speed":4.75}},{"clouds":{"all":88.0},"dt":1.5375528E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":34.0,"pressure":1012.86,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":33.51,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n","id":804.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":341.5,"speed":4.81}},{"clouds":{"all":92.0},"dt":1.5375636E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":46.0,"pressure":1012.12,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":31.51,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n","id":804.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":32.0,"speed":2.8}},{"clouds":{"all":20.0},"dt":1.5375744E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":62.0,"pressure":1012.51,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":28.74,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"few clouds","icon":"02n","id":801.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":101.0,"speed":1.42}},{"clouds":{"all":64.0},"dt":1.5375852E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":62.0,"pressure":1015.08,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":28.89,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d","id":803.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":66.0012,"speed":1.36}},{"clouds":{"all":100.0},"dt":1.537596E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":55.0,"pressure":1015.56,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":31.99,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d","id":804.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":24.001,"speed":3.42}},{"clouds":{"all":76.0},"dt":1.5376068E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":49.0,"pressure":1013.1,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":32.91,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d","id":803.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":330.002,"speed":3.92}},{"clouds":{"all":36.0},"dt":1.5376176E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":44.0,"pressure":1011.77,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":35.15,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d","id":802.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":333.501,"speed":3.56}},{"clouds":{"all":76.0},"dt":1.5376284E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":71.0,"pressure":1014.41,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":29.36,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"light rain","icon":"10n","id":500.0,"main":"Rain"}],"wind":{"deg":47.5027,"speed":2.62}},{"clouds":{"all":48.0},"dt":1.5376392E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":82.0,"pressure":1015.89,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":27.0,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n","id":802.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":55.0006,"speed":2.67}},{"clouds":{"all":32.0},"dt":1.53765E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":87.0,"pressure":1015.38,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":25.87,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n","id":802.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":35.0044,"speed":1.42}},{"clouds":{"all":12.0},"dt":1.5376608E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":91.0,"pressure":1015.74,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":25.01,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"few clouds","icon":"02n","id":801.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":357.505,"speed":1.56}},{"clouds":{"all":24.0},"dt":1.5376716E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":80.0,"pressure":1017.56,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":27.67,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"few clouds","icon":"02d","id":801.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":289.501,"speed":1.28}},{"clouds":{"all":20.0},"dt":1.5376824E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":62.0,"pressure":1017.55,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":32.82,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"few clouds","icon":"02d","id":801.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":290.501,"speed":2.47}},{"clouds":{"all":56.0},"dt":1.5376932E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":53.0,"pressure":1015.2,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":34.52,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"light rain","icon":"10d","id":500.0,"main":"Rain"}],"wind":{"deg":340.0,"speed":3.02}},{"clouds":{"all":56.0},"dt":1.537704E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":53.0,"pressure":1014.61,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":33.81,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"light rain","icon":"10d","id":500.0,"main":"Rain"}],"wind":{"deg":7.00308,"speed":1.91}},{"clouds":{"all":68.0},"dt":1.5377148E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":87.0,"pressure":1017.28,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":26.56,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"moderate rain","icon":"10n","id":501.0,"main":"Rain"}],"wind":{"deg":17.0002,"speed":1.86}},{"clouds":{"all":56.0},"dt":1.5377256E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":94.0,"pressure":1018.2,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":24.22,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"moderate rain","icon":"10n","id":501.0,"main":"Rain"}],"wind":{"deg":68.5074,"speed":1.76}},{"clouds":{"all":32.0},"dt":1.5377364E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":94.0,"pressure":1016.88,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":24.05,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"light rain","icon":"10n","id":500.0,"main":"Rain"}],"wind":{"deg":133.004,"speed":1.23}},{"clouds":{"all":12.0},"dt":1.5377472E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":95.0,"pressure":1017.28,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":23.2,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"few clouds","icon":"02n","id":801.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":269.003,"speed":1.31}},{"clouds":{"all":8.0},"dt":1.537758E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":88.0,"pressure":1019.33,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":26.75,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"02d","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":285.0,"speed":2.17}},{"clouds":{"all":8.0},"dt":1.5377688E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":76.0,"pressure":1019.72,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":32.59,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"02d","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":304.504,"speed":2.56}},{"clouds":{"all":8.0},"dt":1.5377796E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":62.0,"pressure":1017.56,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":34.53,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"02d","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":346.001,"speed":2.16}},{"clouds":{"all":12.0},"dt":1.5377904E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":55.0,"pressure":1016.6,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":33.57,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"few clouds","icon":"02d","id":801.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":30.5009,"speed":1.68}},{"clouds":{"all":48.0},"dt":1.5378012E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":74.0,"pressure":1018.24,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":28.55,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n","id":802.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":153.0,"speed":1.61}},{"clouds":{"all":36.0},"dt":1.537812E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":73.0,"pressure":1018.81,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":27.65,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n","id":802.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":194.503,"speed":3.26}},{"clouds":{"all":56.0},"dt":1.5378228E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":75.0,"pressure":1018.35,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":26.89,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n","id":803.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":252.001,"speed":3.31}},{"clouds":{"all":12.0},"dt":1.5378336E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":78.0,"pressure":1018.48,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":25.53,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"few clouds","icon":"02n","id":801.0,"main":"Clouds"}],"wind":{"deg":280.015,"speed":4.67}},{"clouds":{"all":0.0},"dt":1.5378444E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":81.0,"pressure":1020.49,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":26.99,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"01d","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":289.001,"speed":4.32}},{"clouds":{"all":0.0},"dt":1.5378552E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":63.0,"pressure":1020.85,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":31.94,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"01d","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":298.003,"speed":3.56}},{"clouds":{"all":0.0},"dt":1.537866E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":50.0,"pressure":1018.07,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":35.24,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"01d","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":303.001,"speed":2.66}},{"clouds":{"all":8.0},"dt":1.5378768E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":39.0,"pressure":1016.19,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":35.23,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"02d","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":289.501,"speed":2.35}},{"clouds":{"all":0.0},"dt":1.5378876E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":46.0,"pressure":1017.9,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":29.37,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"01n","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":268.516,"speed":4.26}},{"clouds":{"all":0.0},"dt":1.5378984E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":49.0,"pressure":1019.04,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":26.89,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"01n","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":269.502,"speed":5.31}},{"clouds":{"all":0.0},"dt":1.5379092E9,"main":{"grndLevel":0.0,"humidity":70.0,"pressure":1018.34,"seaLevel":0.0,"temp":24.88,"tempKf":0.0,"tempMax":0.0,"tempMin":0.0},"rain":{"rainVolume":0.0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"weather":[{"description":"clear sky","icon":"01n","id":800.0,"main":"Clear"}],"wind":{"deg":274.0,"speed":5.03}}],"message":0.0122}
```

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha, its also a possible answer, Thanks.